# Criar novo usuario no banco via Rails C

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb

Me ajudem onde está ocorrendo o erro, pq não estou conseguindo identifcar pq o campo não esta sendo reconhecido.

> rails c

```
u = User.new(email:'a@a.com', registration:192536, password:'changeme', password_confirmation:'changeme')
```

Olhem o erro

```
irb(main):002:0> u.save
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (1.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "a@a.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "a@a.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$JieDv.rvWuKi0/34/hooLepn/aKb1a.ZJrlL04m2kJCXFjI3b2JOy"]]
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "registration" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (13, a@a.com, null, $2a$11$JieDv.rvWuKi0/34/hooLepn/aKb1a.ZJrlL04m2kJCXFjI3b2JOy, null, null, null, 0, null, null, null, null).
: INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"
```

Ele não reconhece todo os parametros que estou passando, alguem tem idéia oq pode ser ?

Comment: Tenta checar com u.valid? e olhar os erros u.errors. Pode ajudar.

Comment: isso está com cara que que falta um 'attr_accessor' no model ou alguma outra coisa que está previnindo o mass-assignement em `User.new`. Qual versão do Rails que está sendo utilizada?